# Como pasar de una ventana gráfica a otra en python

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Me gustaría saber como hacer para que en una ventana gráfica al pulsar un Button me abra una nueva ventana con la que interactuar y se cierre la anterior.

También me gustaría saber si se puede hacer que un botón tenga varias funciones como sale en mi código (pero que funcione claro):

```
crearCuenta=Button(frameInicio, text="Crear cuenta", command=conectarBBDD, 
command=crearCuenta)
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo le indicarías al botón que haga una u otra función?

Comment: @XBoss las haría las dos al pulsar el boton

Comment: Pues añade las dos funciones en un método y llama a ese método desde el botón

Comment: Echale un vistazo a Pyside. Puede hacer todo lo que quieres hacer.